# How can you determine if an object has field tracking turned on?

Tags: apex, history-tracking

IS there a way in Apex to determine if a custom object has field tracking turned on? I dont care what the fields are I just need to know if the tracking is turned on

Answer (score 8):

You can querry **FieldDefinition** table in Salesforce which will tell you which fields have history tracking enabled for which object.

eg. If I want to check what fields have history tracking enabled for Opportunity, my query will be

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Opportunity' AND IsFieldHistoryTracked = true
```

And the above query will return me the lists of fields on Opportunity where History tracking is enabled.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm

Note: Make sure your api version is 32 and Above as mentioned in above document **FieldDefinition** is only available after version 32.